# VMWare Can't Connect To Internet

Tags: 18.04, internet, vmware, netplan, systemd-networkd

I am using VMWare ESXi 6.5 with OVH and I am trying to setup an ubuntu 18.04 server. I have successfully created the machine but I am having issues setting up the network connection.

I have followed [this](https://support.us.ovhcloud.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002175944-How-to-Connect-a-VM-to-the-Internet-Using-VMware-ESXi-6-5#ubuntu) tutorial and viewed the troubleshooting page on netplan's website. Everything matches as it says it should. I went over to DebuggingSystemd on the ubuntu wiki and ran those commands, this is the output

When I went to create the vm in the setup it said the network autoconfiguration failed when prompted to setup a network.

```
$ sudo SYSTEM_LOG_LEVEL=debug /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd
ens160: Gained IPv6LL
lo: Link is not managed by us
ens160: Could not set route: Network is unreachable
ens160: Configured
```

Here's the output of `ip a`

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default 1000
    link/ether (pretty sure you're not supposed to give people your mac address) brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 158.69.105.80/30 brd 158.69.105.83 scope global ens160
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe07:2dfb/64 scope link
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yalm`

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [158.69.105.80/30]
      gateway4: 149.56.24.254
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
      routes:
      - to: 158.69.105.80/30
        via: 0.0.0.0
        scope: link
```

If any other information is needed let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified a gateway that you don't have a route to.   149.56.24.254 is not in the network 158.69.105.80/30, therefore it is unreachable and you have not told your system where to send Internet traffic.

You have also specified a redundant `route` entry for the network which is already defined as local due to your `addresses`.

From the tutorial you linked, it looks like what you are meant to be doing is defining a local route to your gateway:

```
routes:
  - to: 149.56.24.254/32
    via: 0.0.0.0
    scope: link
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe I overlooked that, thank you.